# how to match whitespace and alphanumeric characters in python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match a string that has a space in the middle and alphanumeric characters like so:

```
test = django cms
```

I have tried matching using the following pattern:

```
patter = '\s'
```

unfortunately that only matches whitespace, so when a match is found using the search method in the re object, it only returns the whitespace, but not the entire string, how can I change the pattern so that it returns the entire string when finding a match?

Comment: What do you consider an "alphanumeric character?" If letters, numbers and underscores, you'll find \w convenient.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
import re

test = "this matches"
match = re.match('(\w+\s\w+)', test)
print match.groups()
```

returns

```
('this matches',)
```

Comment: (1) redundant parentheses (2) the OP is using `search()` not `match()`

Comment: @John Machin: (1) to my way of thinking the parentheses emphasize that the entire group is returned; (2) it will work equally well with re.search().

Comment: The above regex will work if there is exactly one space in the phrase but I'd suggest changing it to this to match any amount of whitespace-separated words: `match = re.match("([\w|\s]+)", test)`

Answer (score 2):

In case there is more than one space use the following regexp:

```
'([\w\s]+)'
```

example

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: test = "this matches and this"
   ...: match = re.match('([\w\s]+)', test)
   ...: print match.groups()
   ...: 
('this matches and this',)
```